# Cannot manage to add the needed bound to this class declaration; is there a way to do it?

Tags: java, generics

I have two interfaces; the first is this one:

```
public interface ThrowingFunctionalInterface<T extends N, N>
{
    // whatever
}
```

An example implementation of this interface is this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingComparator<T>
    extends Comparator<T>,
    ThrowingFunctionalInterface<ThrowingComparator<T>, Comparator<T>>
{
    // whatever
}
```

Now I want to create an abstract test class because all of these have a lot of common cases in common which can be tested; this is what I came up with until now:

```
@Test
public abstract class AbstractThrowingTestCase<
    T extends ThrowingFunctionalInterface<?, N>, N>
{
    // etc
}
```

I cannot manage to tell that the `ThrowingFunctionalInterface`'s first type argument here should be `T`; is there any way to do it?

---

EDIT: OK, I have managed this:

```
@Test
public abstract class AbstractThrowingTestCase<E extends N,
    T extends ThrowingFunctionalInterface<E, N>, N>
```

That is OK, I guess, except that I have to repeat the `Throwing` version twice... For instance:

```
public final class ThrowingIntPredicateTest
    extends AbstractThrowingTestCase<ThrowingIntPredicate, ThrowingIntPredicate, IntPredicate>
```

Comment: Why are you adding the `@Test` annotation to a class? It is supposed to go on test methods.

Comment: Because it is an abstract class which "real" test classes inherit; if I don't put this annotation at the class level here, gradle's test runner won't find the (extending) test classes. Note: this is TestNG.